# GAE: How to get the blob-image height

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blob, python-imaging-library

Given is the follwing model on GAE:

```
avatar = db.BlobProperty()
```

By calling the image instance properties height or width ([see documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/imageclass.html#Image_height)) with:

```
height = profile.avatar.height
```

the following error is thrown:

> AttributeError: 'Blob' object has no attribute 'height'

PIL is installed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the image is stored in a BlobProperty, then the data is stored in the datastore, and if `profile` is your entity, then the height can be accessed as:

```
from google.appengine.api import images
height = images.Image(image_data=profile.avatar).height
```

If the image is in the blobstore, (blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty in the datastore), then you have 2 ways of doing it, the better way is complicated and requires getting a reader for the blob and feeding it to a exif reader to get the size.  An easier way is:

if `avatar = db.BlobReferenceProperty()` and `profile` is your entity, then:

```
from google.appengine.api import images
img = images.Image(blob_key=str(profile.avatar.key()))

# we must execute a transform to access the width/height
img.im_feeling_lucky() # do a transform, otherwise GAE complains.

# set quality to 1 so the result will fit in 1MB if the image is huge
img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.JPEG,quality=1)

# now you can access img.height and img.width
```

Comment: can you also show the better/complicated method as well here?

Answer (score 5):

A blob is not an image, it is a lump of data.

In order to make an `Image` out of your blob, you have to call [`Image(blob_key=your_blob_key)`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/imageclass.html#Image) if your blob is stored in the blobstore, or `Image(image_data=your_image_data)` if it's stored as a blob in the datastore.

Answer (score 0):

To get image sizes without applying transformations, the image data can be fetched from the blobstore using a `BlobKey` and the size of the data, obtained form `BlobInfo`:

```py
from google.appengine.api import blobstore
from google.appengine.api import images

# ...

image_data = blobstore.fetch_data(blob_key, 0, blob_info.size)
image = images.Image(image_data=image_data)

# image.width and image.height is accessible
```