# Processing image from the blob GAE

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, blob

I managed to store a picture in the Google App engine blob (I can see it in the Blob Viewer from the dashboard, and also in my app using a serving handler)..
However, now that i have this picture there..i want to resize it while serving it to the client...Problem is that i can't do that...I can't make an Image out of that blob...This is my code :

```
from google.appengine.api import images

from google.appengine.ext import blobstore      
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers  
....
class Image(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self,id):
    product = Product.by_id(int(id))
    logging.info('pic key is' + str(product.small_pic.key()))
    img = images.Image(blob_key=str(product.small_pic.key()))
    img.im_feeling_lucky() # do a transform, otherwise GAE complains.

    img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.JPEG,quality=1)
    if img:
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
        self.response.out.write(img)
    else:
        self.error(404)
```

The code from above is taken from this thread : [GAE: How to get the blob-image height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796793/gae-how-to-get-the-blob-image-height/4798806#4798806)

When i run the code from above ex /img/373 i get the error :

**The image "http:..../img/373" cannot be displayed because it contains errors**
How can i do this ?..What i want is to find out way to transform that blob in an image and then process the image...

Comment: In `execute_transforms` you specify the encoding as JPEG and in the response headers you specify it as PNG. This this supposed to be?

Comment: In my many attemps, I commenented the line `img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.JPEG,quality=1)`, still nothing changed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pipe that image through your application.
The gae has a service for resizing images:

```
from google.appengine.api.images import get_serving_url
url = get_serving_url( "blobkey")
```

Then append one of https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions#imgsize values
to that url and you're done.

Comment: I done it this way...it's more efficient because i can keep a big image, and then have it in as many sizes as I want :)

Answer (score 1):

The first answer was close.  This slight refinement lets you adjust the size explicitly:

```
from google.appengine.api.images import get_serving_url
url = get_serving_url( "blobkey",size=1024)
```

In the above code, size=1024 dynamically resizes the source blob image to be 1024 pixels on the longest side while maintaining the original proportion of the image.